# Authenticating Google Drive in Jupyter Lab

Tags: oauth, google-api, jupyter, jupyter-lab

I've followed the steps for authentication on the [JupyterLab Google Drive GitHub page](https://github.com/jupyterlab/jupyterlab-google-drive/blob/master/docs/setup.md). After setting up my credentials on the Google Drive API, I supplied my Client ID to the Jupyter Lab Google Drive settings tab. After doing all that, I received the following message:

> Not a valid origin for the client: http://localhost:8888 has not been whitelisted for client ID dQw4w9WgXcQ-CLUkwYKTj7Q.apps.googleusercontent.com. Please go to https://console.developers.google.com/ and whitelist this origin for your project's client ID.

What is causing this? Do I need to add some sort of whitelist of the `http://localhost:8888` on the Google API end, and if so, how do I do that?

Note: Don't worry, I'm not dumb enough to post my Client ID. Those are two YouTube video IDs.

Answer (score 0):

So apparently the Domain and Policy links provided in the GitHub documentation are not useful for Jupyter Lab. Quite frankly, I'm not sure what they're doing in there--[what is](http://xip.io/) `https://127.0.0.1.xip.io` anyway? Either way, I found further instructions from [Towards Data Science](https://towardsdatascience.com/integrate-jupyterlab-with-google-drive-98d13e340c63), which describes in more specific detail how to whitelist Jupyter Lab on the Google Drive API. I think it's reading in my Drive information, but, being that there are 9 GB of information, it might take a while.